# If it is a date and its before todays date, mark in red. apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to detect:

1. If it is a date
2. If it is before todays date (Regardless of the hour)
3. If point 1 and point 2 are ok, than mark in red.

Can somebody help me please? Here is my google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPW4qbv1K55risE9hpiy5rdYWtmufJb4T3o-3Dzhp-g/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for (var i=2; i<=8; i++){
    var data = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var isDate = data instanceof Date;
  
    var today = now.getTime().getValue();

if(data = isDate && data < today){
    ss.getRange(i,1).setBackground("red");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In the column "A" of the Spreadsheet, when the value is the date object and the date is before today, you want to set the background color of the cell to "red" using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var today = new Date().getTime();
  var colors = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a instanceof Date && a.getTime() < today ? "red" : null]);
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

- When this script is used, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved.
- In your script, `getValue` and `setBackground` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) So, I proposed the above sample script.
- In the above script, the background color of cells is overwritten. For example, if you want to set the background color to only the searched cells, how about the following sample script?

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var today = new Date().getTime();
      var ranges = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flatMap(([a], i) => a instanceof Date && a.getTime() < today ? [`A${i + 2}`] : []);
      sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("red");
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> but that code you offer is a bit advanced for me.

How about the following modified script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var today = new Date().getTime();
  var ranges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] instanceof Date && values[i][0].getTime() < today) {
      ranges.push(`A${i + 2}`);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("red");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that code you offer is a bit advanced for me. Thank you any ways.

Comment: @Francisco Varela Thank you for replying. About `but that code you offer is a bit advanced for me.`, I deeply apologize for this. By the way, from your reply, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If your issue was not resolved, I have to modify my proposed script.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, 7).getValues().flat();
  const bs = sh.getRange(2, 1, 7).getBackgrounds();
  const dt = new Date();
  const td = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
  const tdv = td.valueOf();
  vs.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(e) === '[object Date]' && e.valueOf() < tdv) {
      bs[i][0] = '#ff0000';
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2,1,bs.length,1).setBackgrounds(bs);
}
```